# Связка двух программ Delphi

Tags: сеть, delphi

Имею две программы сделанных на Delphi, чем посоветуете связать для обмена текстом?
Учитывая то, что, порты закрыты провайдером...
Возможно можно как-то веб-сайт использовать для обмена данными, только он на бесплатном хостинге + интернет слабый очень, главное скорость а не качество.
Спасибо.

Comment: когда то для подобной задачи использовал icq. Компонентов для него много. Единственный минус - придется заводить логины для двух аккаунтов.

Comment: помнится там есть компоненты по созданию HTTPServer. Ну идея на одном конце создать мини сервер, а другой будет делать http запрос на тот адрес, а тот отдает нужные данные в текстовом формате

Comment: Они то хороши, но только нужно, что бы хоть кто то был доступен наружу. А это не всегда бывает. Но вместо аськи можно использовать jabber, но у него траффика побольше будет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

аська не вариант, давно уже рабочих компонентов под нее нет.

Скайп, 10 строк кода и общайтесь.

Бесплатный хостинг не подскажу, а вот дешевый с мускулем, тоже вариант, одна таблица и гоняйте себе информацию через базу.

если схема такова что одна программа, отправляет, другая забирает и стирает, то почта, ящик почтовый бесплатный завели. **idPOP3** и **idSMTP** и гоняйте себе текстовые данные. а можно и бинарные.

**DropBox** **YandexДиск** **GoogleDrive** тоже вариант, тем более API открыто

Comment: Скайп - интересный вариант. Я тоже бы его посоветовал.    
Если не ясно - есть Skype API - dll библиотека, которую надо зарегистрировать как ActiveX. С ее помощью можно управлять скайпом на компе. В вашем случае - получать и отправлять сообщения программно.

Comment: скайп не гарантирует доставку сообщений. и в любом случае придется запускать полноценный скайп (есть конечно вариант использовать новомодный skypekit, но он не бесплатный). А запускать скайп... это печалька.

Я слишком много поработал с скайпапи, что бы говорить, что это интересный вариант.

Comment: Скайп запускать обязательно.
я со скайпом тоже работал не мало, вполне рабочий вариант, ни кто не говорил что нужно работать не видимо.

Comment: т.к компьютер без скайпа, нужно что бы просто программу на двух компах запустить и они могут обмен сообщениями делать. был протокол на Delphi TServerSocket, но он зависим от портов...
нельзя ли сделать обработчик на php который бы через связывал 2 программы?

Comment: вы мой ответ читали?
3 варианта предложено, и только один из них при помощи скайпа.
хостинг с базой и почтовик и дропбокс .

да и на сокетах можно, используйте открытый порт, как минимум на любой машине это 80 21 25 110 443 , да и многие до 1024, скорее всего у вас не порты закрыты а адрес не внешний.

на пхп замутить прокладку не получится

Answer (score 0):

Поддерживаю через базу (раз уж socket нельзя). 
На счет дисков добавлю - ukr.net e-disk

Comment: укр.нет не пустит не с украинских ИП, да и апи там совсем не дружественое.